# get user id in another table as foriegn key using session in jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, session

i have two table one for customer and other is order and order table contain a foriegn key with customer_id,so when a customer fill form of  order  as firstname,lastname,city,customer_id. But customer_id field remain empty and when customer post order then customer_id saved using  session  against his order using jsp.how i can do? thanks .

Comment: are u using hibernate or any ORM framework for data handling? If yes and your queries are correct then you probably are missing insert cascade in your relationships. If not then you need transactions to do this is JDBC. Need transaction also with ORM.

Comment: no i am not using framework i just use jsp

Comment: how are you saving data to DB? JDBC? of that's true then use transactions to first create the user record and then save the order. Both things should be done in 1 transaction. Adding the user id in order record insert statement needs to be done manually

Comment: i am working with jsp,msql,tomcate,netbean and establish connection mysql jdbc root 3300 etc and have both table of customer and record but i cant uderstand that in getstring what type of code will be set for get customer_id

Comment: can you post some code here t show the missing pieces.

Comment: <%  String add = request.getParameter("add"); for example here how to get customer id as=request.getParamer("customer_id) using session or any other type of code i have much confusion thanks

Comment: <%  String add = request.getParameter("add");   
    String type = request.getParameter("order_type");
    String city = request.getParameter("city");
    String veh = request.getParameter("vehicles");
    String date = request.getParameter("order_date");
     String user = request.getParameter("users_id"); here how to get customer id which is login currently

Comment: oh ok so u mean to read customer_id form session.If you have the customer_id in session already then you can read it like this. Enable session in jsp first using <%@ page session="true" %> then do <% request.getSession().getAttribute("name") %> to read the session value.

Comment: do upvote the answer if it helped

Comment: why not but i am new and not allowed sory now i insert your code in request string but it give error for this section (.getAttribute("name") %>) can i not write it as(String user = request.getSession()("users_id");)

Comment: yes you can. please read on google about <% and <%= JSP syntaxes.